# Vue/Javascript - Q-Select Filtering when Options is populated from database?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, quasar

I have a problem with writing a filter function to use in a Q-Select when the options list are obtained from an async function that obtains a list (of at least 10,000+ Record IDs) from a database. The sample code that is provided in Q-Select documentation page in Quasar has the options initially hardcoded, and I'm having a hard time making it work when in my case.

Here's the template for the q-select I'm using:

```
<template>
          <q-select
            filled
            v-model="this.record_id"
            use-input
            input-debounce="0"
            @filter="filterFn"
            label="Record ID"
            :options="this.record_id_list"
          >
            <template v-slot:no-option>
              <q-item>
                <q-item-section class="text-grey">
                  No results
                </q-item-section>
              </q-item>
            </template>
          </q-select>

</template>
```

Here's the snippet of the Vue script. I think the problem is that the fetching of the record_id_list is only done during created() step, but the filter function is written with this.record_id_list still being empty. I'm not really sure how to reconcile that.

```
<script>
export default {
  setup: function() {
    return {
      record_id_list: ref([]),
      record_id: ref(''),

      filterFn (val, update) {
        ...
      }
  },

  methods: {

    async fetchSourceList(){

      await this.$api.get('<URL REDACTED>').then(res => {
        this.record_id_list = res.data.record_ids
      })

    },

  },

  created() {
    this.fetchSourceList()
  },
}

</script>
```

Here's the sample code that is in Quasar's documentation for q-select that I wanted to adapt. Taken from (https://quasar.dev/vue-components/select):

```
<template>
  <div class="q-pa-md">
    <div class="q-gutter-md row">
      <q-select
        filled
        v-model="model"
        use-input
        input-debounce="0"
        label="Simple filter"
        :options="options"
        @filter="filterFn"
        style="width: 250px"
      >
        <template v-slot:no-option>
          <q-item>
            <q-item-section class="text-grey">
              No results
            </q-item-section>
          </q-item>
        </template>
      </q-select>

    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const stringOptions = [
  'Google', 'Facebook', 'Twitter', 'Apple', 'Oracle'
]

export default {
  setup () {
    const options = ref(stringOptions)

    return {
      model: ref(null),
      options,

      filterFn (val, update) {
        if (val === '') {
          update(() => {
            options.value = stringOptions

            // here you have access to "ref" which
            // is the Vue reference of the QSelect
          })
          return
        }

        update(() => {
          const needle = val.toLowerCase()
          options.value = stringOptions.filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle) > -1)
        })
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```